# Conditional random variables

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

How to generate three random variable $a, b, c$ of some distributions that satisfy:
$$a \in [0, 0.5]$$
$$b \in [0, 0.4]$$
$$c \in [0, 0.3]$$
$$a+b+c = 1$$

Comment: This seems to be missing some essential details.  What do you mean by "how to generate"?  And what do you mean by "of some distributions"?

Comment: By example $a, b, c$ of uniform distributions and I have a generator of uniform random variables. How can I draw samples of $a,b,c$?

Comment: It is not possible that $a,b,c$ have each an uniform distribution,  when perhaps $a = 0.01, b = 0.01$ you cannot find a $c \in [0,0.3]$ so that $a+b+c=1$

Comment: @user2863620 Please clarify your question or provide some context what you need this numbers for so we can perhaps work out another solution.

Answer (score 2):

The first three conditions define a shoebox in 3d, while the fourth condition is a plane slicing through.  Luckily its intersection is a simple shape, namely a triangle with vertices at $(0.5,0.2,0.3), (0.3, 0.4,0.3), (0.5, 0.4, 0.1)$.  Choose a point uniformly on this skew triangle.  This is not the only possible construction, but I think a case could be made that this is the most natural one to provide "uniform" distributions.

Note: one way to get a point  on this triangle is to choose $\lambda, \mu, \kappa$ each uniformly in $[0,1]$ and then your desired point is
$$\frac{\lambda}{\lambda+\mu+\kappa}(0.5,0.2,0.3)+\frac{\mu}{\lambda+\mu+\kappa}(0.3,0.4,0.3)+\frac{\kappa}{\lambda+\mu+\kappa}(0.5,0.4,0.1)$$

However, as the comments point out, this is not uniform, and tends to cluster near the center of the triangle.

Comment: But then you are gonna have the problem that not all values of e.g. $a \in [0,0.5]$ are covered.

Comment: There is no choice of $b,c$ that works for $a<0.3$.

Comment: This is the best way one can properly define the problem, I think. As stated the problem is invalid, as vadim123 and flawr have pointed out. That said, I think there should be a way to formalize this with conditional expectation.

Comment: Cf. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/876212/uniform-distribution-on-convex-hull. I think we have concluded (by broadening the context) that this approach is not correct. In particular, a region near the corner of the triangle will be assigned smaller probability than a region near the center even though they have the same area. My guess is that the problem is basically http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel%E2%80%93Kolmogorov_paradox

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this is to embed your problem in a 2-D subspace:

1. Associate $a\rightarrow x$, $b\rightarrow y$,$c\rightarrow z$
2. Let $u=(-1,0,1),v=(-1,1,0)$ be be two vectors that span the solution space of $x+y+z=1$
3. Let $\lambda_1,\lambda_2 \sim U(0,1)$
4. Set $P=\lambda_1u+\lambda_2v+(1,0,0)$ (we're starting from the solution $x=1,y=z=0$)
5. Check the components of $P:P_i \in [0,M_i]$ where $M_i$ is the upper bounds of the associated variables.
6. If so, then accept the answer as a validate draw from the joint distribution, otherwise reject and repeat.

However, your marginals will not match what you specified because each variable MUST be >0 to achieve your constraint. In particular, $a\in [.3,.5], b\in [.2,.4],c\in[.2,.3]$